# Updating Twitter Status

Tags: php, encoding, twitter

I'm trying to add some twitter funcionality to my website (php). I publish links like

http://twitter.com/home?status=Hello World

When the twitter page loads, the text box appears with the text

```
       Hello%20World
```

That is, with the text url-encoded. I suppose that it's related with the encoding of the page (actually, windows-1252) but i can´t figure out wich is the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: ... and you have set the authentication headers I guess...

Comment: Can you post how your link is constructed? It appears to me as though twitter is decoding properly, I'm wondering if something is being double-encoded on your input.

Comment: Why don't you use the twitter's API?

Comment: I just want to drop a link that allows user update his own status, so i don´t need the API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hello+world](http://twitter.com/home?status=Hello+world)